# What is really happening in this Typescript code. Having result is wrong with the hardcode string and parameterized string

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I have a method to do some typeorm actions on an entity.

```
  async deactivateBarcode(barcode: string) {
let currentBarcode: Barcode = await this.barcodeRepository.findOne({
  code: barcode,
});

currentBarcode.isActive = true;

return await this.barcodeRepository.save(currentBarcode);
```

}

this prints an error message for the line "currentBarcode.isActive'

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'isActive' of undefined
```

but when I hard code the barcode value in to the { code: 'hardcodebarcode'}, the line 'currentBarcode.isActive' has value and it works..

```
 async deactivateBarcode(barcode: string) {
let currentBarcode: Barcode = await this.barcodeRepository.findOne({
  code: '3sfsdfsderer',
});

currentBarcode.isActive = true;

return await this.barcodeRepository.save(currentBarcode);
```

}

My question, what is happening in this method which is causing this different behavior that
'when passed as parameter' or 'when hardcoded the same value'..

Comment: Probably you call deactivateBarcode with a value that is not "3sfsdfsderer" ...

Comment: I feel stupid asking this question now.. It was the NestJS body decorator extracting it as a an object other than a string. my bad... thanks for the reply ..